# Splunk lookuptable

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a `csv` with different kind of IoCs in it like email addresses, IPs, etc. I want to run a search on any of my indexes which would return each record that has any match with my list.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
index=* "item1" OR "item2" OR "item3"
```

Since I have a thousand items on my list this won't work. So, I uploaded my csv as a `lookuptable` and tried the following:

```
index=* [| inputlookup  test.csv]
```

This returns nothing, but if I search for each item "manually" then I get results.
What am I missing?

Comment: This [Splunk Answers Link](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/468612/how-to-search-a-lookup-table-and-return-the-matchi.html) looks like it contains what you are trying to figure out how to do. I don't really want to steal someone else's answer though

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know the format of your CSV, but this should help.

```
index=* [| inputlookup  test.csv | format]
```

If you insist on using `index=*`, do yourself a favor and use a small time window.